# Equivalent of RepositionThemeTransition in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, layout, windows-store-apps

In windows store applications, a RepositionThemeTransition can be added to UI elements in order to make them swoop instead of teleporting when their positions change. There are also other types of transitions.

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <RepositionThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Rectangle>
</Rectangle>
```

WPF doesn't appear to support this functionality. Is there a way to do something equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just emulating the functionality myself, by applying animations in LayoutUpdated events that initially counteract changes in position. Here's the code:

```
public static void AddRepositionTransitionsUsingRenderTransform(this FrameworkElement control, bool x = true, bool y = true, CancellationToken lifetime = default(CancellationToken)) {
    if (control == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("control");
    var approachPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

    // animate when positions change, to give a 'swooping' effect instead of teleporting
    var transform = new TranslateTransform();
    var oldPosition = May<Point>.NoValue;
    EventHandler updated = (sender, arg) => {
        // determine where the control has moved to
        var newPosition = control.ActualWidth == 0 || control.ActualHeight == 0 || control.Visibility != Visibility.Visible
                        ? May<Point>.NoValue
                        : control.TranslatePoint(new Point(-transform.X, -transform.Y), Application.Current.MainWindow);
        if (oldPosition == newPosition) return;

        // adjust the animation to initially cancel the change in position, and finish at the new final position after the approach period
        var dif = (from o in oldPosition
                    from n in newPosition
                    select new Point(n.X - o.X, n.Y - o.Y)
                    ).ElseDefault();
        if (x) transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, new DoubleAnimation(transform.X - dif.X, 0, approachPeriod));
        if (y) transform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, new DoubleAnimation(transform.Y - dif.Y, 0, approachPeriod));

        oldPosition = newPosition;
    };

    // register for events and replace transform, until lifetime ends
    var oldTransform = control.RenderTransform;
    control.RenderTransform = transform;
    control.LayoutUpdated += updated;
    lifetime.Register(() => {
        control.LayoutUpdated -= updated;
        control.RenderTransform = oldTransform;
    });
}
```

Note that "May" is a custom option type, so that part won't compile. You can use the type Point? instead, with explicit null checks instead of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is the `FluidMoveBehavior` behavior in [Blend's SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801). There are several tutorials available on the web - [here's one](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2010/10/12/blend-bits-14-fluid-movement.aspx) in case you're not familiar with behaviors or this specific behavior.

Comment: Could you give an example of how it's used?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on how I use blend's sdk in a WPF project. When I try to open blend for visual studio I can't even create a new project (the new project dialog's OK button does nothing)...